# Unable to auth as user programmatically

Tags: python, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm using the following code (python, but it doesn't really matter, getting the same result with powershell and invoke-webrequest):

```
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import UserPassCredentials
username = '%username%'
password = '%password%'
client_id = '{Azure AD Application GUID}'
secret_id = '{Azure AD Application secret}'
credentials = UserPassCredentials(username, password, client_id, secret_id)
```

this works for users in one tenant, but doesn't work for the users from another tenant with a weird error:

> msrest.exceptions.AuthenticationError: , InvalidGrantError:
>   (invalid_grant) AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials.
>   AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password

I can login using the portal with the same credentials just fine. The tenant in question is using AAD Sync and SSO, could that interfere?

If yes, how do I obtain tokens for the users in such an Azure AD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure understand the serious security implications of using the **Resource owner password credential grant** when try to login with Azure AD.

There are also a couple of issues/side effects with it:

- If your account is MFA / Conditional Access enabled, then you won't be to login using the resource owner password credential grant. Period. There is no way.
- If your domain is `federated` (like in your case), you won't be able to login. There is a slight chance, that it would be possible to login, if you also do Password Hash Sync, but I am not sure whether this would help.

At the end, the best way to authenticate a back-end-and-non-user-interactive process, is by using `Service Principal`.

Check out the following documentation sources to learn more about service principals in Azure AD and how authenticate using a service principal:

- [Applications and Service Principals in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects)
- [Using PowerShell to create service principal and access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal)

Comment: so I need to obtain a token with username in it, how do I use service principal auth?

Comment: involve user interaction to ask the user for `authorization` - the Authorization code grant. Then use the refresh token (which has a default lifetime of 90 days) to update your access token. If the authorization expires - you have to ask for it again. This is the right way to get tokens with user information. Otherwise, as already said - back-end process does not represent a real user - so use service principal.